# Cast to pointer from integer of different size (passing int as a const void * parameter)

Tags: c, 64-bit, void-pointers

I have to maintain a chunk of source code on Linux with gcc which has the following function prototype:

```
int foo(const void*, ...)
```

I have to pass an integer into this function. I know that this is a bad idea but at this stage, I'm not allowed to modify the source code.

i.e I have to call `foo(n)` (`n` is defined as `int n`)

On a 64-bit machine, I get an error:

```
cast to pointer from integer of different size
```

As I understand, this is because the size of an integer on a 32-bit machine is four bytes while the size of a pointer to a void is eight bytes.

I resolve the compilation error by first casting the integer with size 4 bytes to a long with size 8 bytes. So I did `foo((long)n)`

I wonder if this is an acceptable way to deal with this issue or are there other suggestions?

Comment: If you can't modify the code then what sort of solution are you looking for here ?

Comment: @PaulR He probably meant that he cannot modify `foo`. Library function perhaps.

Comment: You should give more context. If `foo` will use the value you pass it, then either it already has provisions for accepting integer values passed as `const void *`, and you should use those provisions, or passing it an integer value results in behavior it was not designed for. Alternatively, if `foo` will not use the value but merely holds it for later return to your code (e.g., the way `qsort` accepts a pointer to void but only passes pointers back to your code), then should likely pass `foo` a pointer to an `int` that contains your value. So, why are you passing `foo` an integer value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `intptr_t`, but it is optional and may not be available in `stdint.h`:

```
intptr_t n = 1;
foo((void*)n);
```